# Using Play!Framework 2.2 subprojects

Tags: playframework-2.2

I'm trying to split my Play!Framework 2.2 project in  subprojects and I have some hard time figuring it out.

Here's my folder structure :

```
MyProject/
 | - app/
 | --- controllers/ # containing some main controllers
 | --- views/ # resulting views
 | - build.sbt # see after
 | - conf/
 | --- application.conf
 | --- routes
 | --- modules/ # My modules folder, aka sub projects
 | -------- common/
 | ------------ app/
 | --------------- models/ # The models
 | --------------- utils/
 | -------- api/
 | -------- web/
 | ------------ app/ # some controllers/views
 | ------------ conf/ # routes mainly
 | ------------ app/ # some controllers/views
 | ------------ conf/ # routes mainly
```

(I simplified it).

The main `routes` file :

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                             controllers.StaticPages.index()

# Web
->  /html/v1 web.Routes

# API
->  /api/v1  api.Routes
```

web.routes :

```
# HTML Engine renderer
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

GET   /users                controllers.Users.list()
```

api.routes :

```
# API
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

GET   /users                controllers.Users.list()
```

And finally, my `build.sbt`

```
import play.Project._

name := "My project"

version := "1.0-alpha"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.25",
  "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.2.0"
)

play.Project.playJavaSettings

lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
    .dependsOn(common, web, api)
    .aggregate(common, web, api)

lazy val web = project.in(file("modules/web"))
    .dependsOn(common)

lazy val api = project.in(file("modules/api"))
    .dependsOn(common)

lazy val common = project.in(file("modules/common"))
```

When cleaning/compiling and running, I face this error :

> not found: value web
>   In /path/to/project/conf/routes at line 20.
>   ->  /html/v1 web.Routes

If I remove the `->` in the main `routes` file, Play! cannot find the package utils in common.

So I guess common, web and api aren't loaded, but why?

### Update

Since @James-roper helped me found the problem, I created a Github repository that shows a simple Play!Framework 2.2 project with sub projects. You can find it here : https://github.com/cnicodeme/play2.2-subproject

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your sub projects need to use different package names, at the moment they are conflicting.

Comment: I tried with a really simple sub project, containing only a `controllers.admin.Admin.class` file, and the route mapping to the `index()` of the previous mentionned class, that only return a `ok("good");`. The package names are different, but still, I got the same error.

Comment: In the sample project you've given me, you didn't declare a dependency between the admin project and the root project.  I added this to it and it works fine for me:

    lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).aggregate(admin).dependsOn(admin)
    
    lazy val admin = project.in(file("admin"))

Comment: I updated the github repo to show a simple splitted project in Play 2.2 for others that seeks help.

Comment: @Cyril N. Thanks on example, i have just 1 question. Using play 2.2.1, i created new play project and in build.sbt i added same line like you in github-examples. After play compile and play eclipse form command line i get following http://pokit.org/get/?557452cb165b30f7cebac1ea8a6e630a.jpg, what to do next? as i can see this project in modules are not play projects.

Comment: Treat them as play projects, like adding app/controllers, app/models, app/views, conf/ in admin/ and it should work. (don't forget the build.sbt in each sub modules)

Comment: As i understand you, i must manually to add play structure to this sub-models :S ? So i need to manually add app/controllers, routes etc ?